# Will I harm my SSD if Windows 10 image created from an old HDD with 512 bytes per sector is installed on it?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, migration

I am using Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500 GB.
Instead of installing a fresh copy of Windows 10 on it, an old image of the OS created from an old HHD was used
I am worried this may affect the performance/age of the SSD. Which I understood is made to run on 4k bytes per sector.

screenshots are on my laptop now after the migration to the ssd.
[image: fsutil]
[image: system info]

Comment: That is a restriction of the hard drive not the image, so no there will be no issue.

Comment: "*Which I understood is made to run on 4k bytes per sector.*" -- Which of the two screenshots that you included and annotated says that? `Bytes Per Sector: 512` or `Bytes/Sector 512`?

Comment: @techraf my worry is because this OS is an image of an old HDD, it kept the sectors/clusters settings, and they are not what an SSD need.
am not good in hard disks, it is just that I am worried that the OS is forcing the ssd to work in a way that is not ideal for the disk
So my worry is that sectors are not well aligned to work properly on the new drive

Comment: ...and because you are worried it means the question doesn't have to be consistent?

Comment: In my investigation of the limitations of image programs, there is only one tool that claims they can go from a smaller sector size to a larger sector size, when you store the image to the HDD.  I would provide the name of that program, but honestly, I am not sure if its one of two programs I have marked as potential purchases so I won't attempt to guess and give you wrong information.

Comment: @techraf I have updated my comment above, while you were commenting. 
In short, I read somewhere that SSD need to be working on 4k bytes per sector. and the OS seems (from both screenshots I generated) to have different configuration than what is ideal for the SSD. I think if I had freshly installed Windows (instead of image from old hhd) on the SSD, the above info in screenshots would have showed 4k bytes per sector..
Did I make my question clearer?

Comment: @Ramhound so you think the way OS is configured is wrong for the SSD?
I think the best software to have used for that is EASEUS http://www.easeus.com/support/todo-backup/clone-a-hard-disk.html
It has an option to OPTIMIZE FOR SSD.

Comment: @Postscripter - I didn't say that.  I just mention there are tools to convert a disk image with a 512-byte sector size and restore it to a 4k-byte sector size.  What you do with that information is up to you.  "I think if I had freshly installed Windows" you should verify this is even the case.

Comment: @rahmound I know you did not say that. Now, do you think the SSD will perform better if I changed to 4k byte size?

Comment: I didn't say that either.  I am saying you should determine if that will be the case.  I can't do the benchmarking so I can't prove anything  one way or another

Answer (score 1):

You have no problems as your sectors are aligned properly.

Many manufacturers have set their hard disks to 4k per sector but considering compatibility with operating system, manufacturers emulate a 4k sector to 8 512-byte sectors to manage data, which is the so called 512e.

Moreover, as NTFS becomes the standard file system whose default allocation unit size (cluster size) is 4K, the physical 4K sector may be misaligned with the 4K cluster.

As a result, reading data in 1 cluster will read 2 physical 4K sectors so that data read and write speed will be reduced. Cluster size is set by the system rather than hard disk manufacturers.

Therefore, it is very necessary to make them aligned if we want to get best SSD optimization, and to align partition can achieve this goal.

In Windows 7 and more recent OS, all newly created partitions will be aligned automatically. However, if you migrate Windows to SSD or change partition size and location on SSD frequently, your partitions may be misaligned. To check whether partitions are aligned:

Run diskpart as administrator and type these commands one by one: 
`list disk`,
`select disk n` (n being the number of SSD),
`list partition`.

If the value under "Offset" can be divided by 4, the very partition is aligned.  For example if the offset value is 32K it is aligned as 32/4 gives a whole number (8). However, if the volume cannot be divided by 4, you will need to [perform a partition alignment](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/align-all-partitions.html).

Another way of checking alignment is to look at "partition starting offset" in your second picture. 173,012,942,848 bytes can be divided by 4k (4096 bytes).  173,012,942,848/4096=42,239,488

Comment: Thanks @chris for you answer, I have checked as per your instructions, the offset is ok.

"As a result, reading data in 1 cluster will read 2 physical 4K sectors so that data read and write speed will be reduced."
 In my case is this happening, can I avoid it if format and reinstall a fresh copy of Windows 10?

Comment: This is not happening as everything is aligned therefore all clusters are held within their relevant sector. If they are misaligned you could have a cluster spanning two sectors leading to having to read 2 physical sectors for that cluster